# Error al eliminar node_modules permiso denegado

Tags: npm

El problema que tenía era que, debido a una tontería (culpa mía) no pude ejecutar el comando `npm run start` en un proyecto con Webpack. La solución era eliminar y reinstalar **node_modules** pero no podía acceder a él.

- Intenté de todo. Instalé `rimraf`
- Intente cambiar los permisos por Ubuntu (en windows 10) y cmd
- Lo comprimí (parcialmente) en un *.rar* para luego eliminarlo

Nada funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Hoy descargué el proyecto desde GitHub (porque lo borré todo menos node_modules) pero después de hacerlo ahora no podía acceder al repo. Volví a abrir Ubuntu, esta vez como administrador, ejecuté `rm -rf Stories` y listo.

No tengo idea de porqué. Esto no pasó ayer. Supongo que apagar la laptop influyó en algo, pero ya lo borré.

Answer (score 0):

Instala nuevamente los módulos que tenías con tu "package.json". Ejecuta en donde lo tengas:

```
npm install
```

Esto debería generarte los modulos de tu "node_modules" nuevamente.

Comment: Sí, lo hice y me funcionó. De hecho la volví  a cagar xD Pero pude resolverlo. Básicamente tuve que borrar todo lo relacionado a Node (excepto nvm) y volverlo a instalar. Claro, también eliminar y reinstalar los módulos y listo. Complejo y tedioso. Pero al menos pude resolver todo.